# Protobuf-C Compilation Issue

Tags: c, protocol-buffers

I'm feeling a bit thick, but when I run through even basic examples provided on http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/wiki/Examples, I keep getting the following build errors:

```
/tmp/cc19catp.o: In function `main':
packit.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `amessage__descriptor'
packit.c:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `amessage__get_packed_size'
packit.c:(.text+0xdb): undefined reference to `amessage__pack'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm compiling with the following command:

```
gcc -o pack -lprotobuf-c packit.c
```

Anyone else have this problem?  I feel I'm missing something basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gcc -o pack packit.c amessage.pb-c.c -lprotobuf-c
```

You must compile and link the `proto-c`-generated code.

Also, in general, when `foo` depends on `bar`, `foo` should precede `bar` in the linker command.